# How to write this query in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent

```
SELECT *
FROM gen_monumentos
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(cgm_atrimestrales.ATRI_intId),cgm_atrimestrales.*
FROM cgm_atrimestrales
GROUP BY MONU_intId DESC) AS AA
ON gen_monumentos.MONU_intId=AA.MONU_intId
LEFT JOIN cgm_acciones on cgm_acciones.ACCI_intId=AA.ACCI_intId
```

I make the query and the desired results in MySQL, but I need with jquery to display the information in a page. I tried:

```
public function monumento()
{
    $monumentos = \DB::table('gen_monumentos')
        ->leftJoin( DB::raw( 
            'SELECT MAX( cgm_atrimestrales.ATRI_intId ),cgm_atrimestrales.* FROM cgm_atrimestrales GROUP BY MONU_intId DESC' ), function( $leftJoin)
            {
                $leftJoin->on( 'cgm_atrimestrales.MONU_intId', '=', 'gen_monumentos.MONU_intId' );
            })
        ->leftJoin('cgm_acciones','cgm_acciones.ACCI_intId','=','cgm_atrimestrales.ACCI_intId')
        ->select('gen_monumentos.*','cgm_atrimestrales.*','cgm_acciones.ACCI_varDescripcion')
        ->get();


    return \Response::json($monumentos);
}
```

But  it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more 
research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Post what you've tried thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it,
In case someone had a similar problem, here is the solution

```
$monumentos = \DB::table('gen_monumentos')
                 ->leftJoin( DB::raw( 
                    '(
                       SELECT MAX( cgm_atrimestrales.ATRI_intId ),
                         cgm_atrimestrales.*
                       FROM cgm_atrimestrales
                       GROUP BY MONU_intId DESC)
                       as AA
                    '),
                    function( $leftJoin) {
                         $leftJoin->on(
                              'AA.MONU_intId',
                              '=',
                              'gen_monumentos.MONU_intId'
                         );
                 })
                 ->leftJoin(
                       'cgm_acciones',
                       'cgm_acciones.ACCI_intId','=','AA.ACCI_intId'
                 )
                 ->select(
                       'gen_monumentos.*',
                       'AA.*',
                       'cgm_acciones.ACCI_varDescripcion'
                 )
                 ->get();
```